# GWT java.io.File server package

Tags: java, file, gwt, smartgwt, java-io

I was looking for hours now, but I can't find what I'm looking for. I know java.io.File is not supported in the GWT client package. I want to use it inside the server package. When I compile the app i get the following error:

```
Compiling module com.xxx.yyy.GWTApp
      Validating units:
  [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/.../workspace/GWTApp/src/com/xxx/yyy/server/Class1.java'
     [ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type java.io.File; did you forget to inherit a required module?
  [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/.../workspace/GWTApp/src/com/xxx/yyy/server/Class2.java'
     [ERROR] Line 104: No source code is available for type java.io.BufferedReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [ERROR] Line 104: No source code is available for type java.io.FileReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     ...
```

Any Ideas what could be wrong?

Edit *.gwt.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='yyy'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <entry-point class='com.xxx.yyy.client.Yyy'/>
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
  <source path='server'/>
  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
</module>
```

Comment: It should not. Can you paste a image with your package structure ?

Comment: Your classes com.xxx.yyy.server.Class1 and com.xxx.yyy.server.Class2 are most probably imported somewhere in your client classes. Try to search in the imports and remove the references to those classes.

Comment: package structure: [link](http://oi62.tinypic.com/15ydmcw.jpg)

Comment: @Julien No, that's not the problem, i don't use them in any client class

Comment: Can you show your `*.gwt.xml`?

Comment: @Armin it looks like your server classes were imported by the way :) I'm glad you could solve your problem thanks to David.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this line from your `*.gwt.xml`:

```
<source path='server'/>
```

The source tag is used to identify the packages that need to be compiled to javascript. Server packages should not be included.